# Magento data migration tool - source and destination documetns are not mapped?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I'm currently trying to migrate from M1 to M2 using the data migration tool provided by magento. After configuring config.xml and running the command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml
```

I receive the following errors:

```
[2020-02-26 15:27:26][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: core_store,core_store_group,core_website
[2020-02-26 15:27:26][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: store,store_group,store_website
```

I've checked my config for map.xml.dist and I've checked my map.xml.dist for ignoring the documents, so I'm confused and need help.

Anyone pls?

My config.xml changes:

```
    <source>
    <database host="127.0.0.1" name="somename" user="someuser" password="somepassword"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="127.0.0.1" name="somename" user="someuser" password="somepassword"/>
</destination>

<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map.xml</map_file>
<crypt_key>somekey</crypt_key>
```

Database m1 screenshot:
[image: Database m1 screenshot]

Database m2 screenshot:
[image: Database m2 screenshot]

SOLUTION:
Apparently I switched the names between my m1 db name and my m2 db name in my config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is source_prefix and dest_prefix error.

You add the source prefix.

Open the config.xml file and search the source_prefix and add the your magento 1 database source prefix

Ex:-

```
<source_prefix>add the magento 1 database prefix</source_prefix>
<dest_prefix>Optional</dest_prefix>
```

Comment: Don't understand. My table_prefix is empty?

Comment: Please send the your database table screenshot

Comment: I've added them in the question :)

Comment: Magento 1 database table image please one new add because I have not understand this images

Comment: The upper one is my m1 database. I imported my m1 database into the server of where my m2 database is.

Comment: Yes but you the more table name screen shot add

Comment: And more This error happens when M1 or M2 use prefix in tables name. Please add your prefix in config.xml file in tags

Comment: https://ibb.co/x2HpJx3 Look this is from my local.xml file m1. No table_prefix. U are also able to see in the picture above that my tables in m1 database doesn't have prefixes. So I leave it empty in my config.xml

Comment: Omggggg sry I just discovered that the reason it didn't work is because I switched between m1 and m2 databases in config.xml :///

Comment: So solve your issues??

Comment: Yes. I solved it.

Comment: if helpful this answers so please accept..

Answer (score 0):

Rename Magento 1 table with Magento 2 in `map.xml.dist` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="map.xsd">
    <source>
        <document_rules>
            <rename>
                <document>core_store</document>
                <to>store</to>
            </rename>
            <rename>
                <document>core_store_group</document>
                <to>store_group</to>
            </rename>
            <rename>
                <document>core_website</document>
                <to>store_website</to>
            </rename>
        </document_rules>
    </source>
</map>
```

Comment: What? Not sure I understand... I have this file. This is my map-stores.xml. Atleast some of it.

Comment: Add rename in `map.xml.dist`.